# Debian live install ''How to launch the installer on the terminal without aborting the live session?''

Tags: debian, terminal, debian-installer

On debian Jessie Live CD it is possible to run the installer by choosing **Install debian Jessie** or by running `sudo debian-installer-launcher` from the terminal , but the installer will be launched on full screen.

Is that possible to launch debian installer in the terminal and keep using the live session?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation,

```
sudo debian-installer-launcher --text
```

will launch the text-mode installer in a new terminal window.

Comment: unfortunately it seems to have changed in stretch and i don't seem to find its new name. i'm staring at a booted debian 9.4 live pendrive, and the installer is nowhere to be found.

Comment: @Attila it was removed in Stretch (Debian 9), see [#844611](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=844611) for details.

Comment: But it can be installed later. https://packages.debian.org/stretch/debian-installer-launcher

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with Debian 9 (Strech), the program is not installed by default and needs to be installed manually:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install debian-installer-launcher
```

Now you can launch it:

```
sudo debian-installer-launcher
# or
sudo debian-installer-launcher --text
```